# Session.Transaction changes after Rollback (NHibernate)

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

I have the following code (simplified for the sake of discussion). What I don't understand is why the `session.Transaction` property returns a different transaction after a rollback.

For instance, this means that the property `Session.Transaction.WasRolledBack` is of little help unless I store a reference to the first transaction and check that transaction's property.

Can anybody provide some insight here?

```
int transId = session.Transaction.GetHashCode();

using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
   Assert.AreEqual(transId, tx.GetHashCode());

   tx.Rollback();

   Assert.AreEqual(transId, tx.GetHashCode());
   Assert.AreEqual(transId, session.Transaction.GetHashCode()); // Fails
}
```

**Update:**

David Walschots' answer is very helpful and precise. Also, I found the following in the [Nhibernate Documentation](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-endingsession-commit):

> If you rollback the transaction you should immediately close and discard the current session to ensure that NHibernate's internal state is consistent."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From NHibernate in Action (Kuaté, Harris, Bauer, King):

> After committing a transaction, the NHibernate session replaces it
>   with a new transaction. This means you should keep a reference to the
>   transaction you're committing if you think you'll need it afterward.
>   This is necessary if you need to call transaction.WasCommited.
>   session.Transaction.WasCommitted always returns false.

Most likely the same applies to the `Transaction.WasRolledBack` property.