# Fluent NHibernate - good complete working Helper class for managing SessionFactory/Session?

Tags: class, fluent-nhibernate, helper

I was going through [nHibernate Helper Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310691/nhibernate-good-complete-working-helper-class-for-managing-sessionfactory-sessi) question on SO... I would like to get a helper class for `fluent nHibernate`...  can anyone provide/refer a proper OO type helper class for managing a singleton of the SessionFactory and then also for managing Sessions?

Comment: It's the same, really. There is no difference. Or maybe you want something else...

Comment: @Mauricio i started with Fluent nhibernate straight away without studing nhibernate so i thought of getting a helper class... Can i use the same helper class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fluent NHibernate is only a layer on top of NHibernate's mapping API, allowing the programmer to map entities using code and conventions instead of XML or attributes. It has no relation to NHibernate's sessions.

Most of the code for NHibernate (including helpers for session factories and sessions) applies to Fluent NHibernate as well.