# Will my session be automatically closed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

**Edit**

Orignal Title: My transaction is closed by the time it gets to my Repo. What am I doing wrong?

I got a answer to my origanl questions(I forgot to open the transaction lol). Now I am wondering if my code is automatically closing the session or if I have to somehow tell it to do this.

---

Hi

I am using mvc 3.0, nhibernate, fluent nhibernate and ninject 2.0

Global.asax

```
// Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            // Hook our DI stuff when application starts
            SetupDependencyInjection();


            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }


        public void SetupDependencyInjection()
        {         
            // Tell ASP.NET MVC 3 to use our Ninject DI Container
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(CreateKernel()));
        }

        protected IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var modules = new INinjectModule[]
                              {
                                 new NhibernateModule(),
                                 new ServiceModule(),
                                 new RepoModule()
                              };

            return new StandardKernel(modules);
        }

    }
```

Session Factory

```
public class NhibernateSessionFactory
    {
        public ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
        {
            ISessionFactory fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure()
                                                  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("test")))
                                                  .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyMaps>())
                                                  .BuildSessionFactory();

            return fluentConfiguration;
        }
    }
```

Session Factory Provider

```
 public class NhibernateSessionFactoryProvider : Provider<ISessionFactory>
    {   
        protected override ISessionFactory CreateInstance(IContext context)
        {
            var sessionFactory = new NhibernateSessionFactory();
            return sessionFactory.GetSessionFactory();
        }
    }
```

Nhibernate Module

```
 public class NhibernateModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToProvider<NhibernateSessionFactoryProvider>().InSingletonScope();
            Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(context => context.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InRequestScope();
        }
    }
```

Service Module

```
  public class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ITest>().To<Test>();
        }
    }
```

Repo Module

```
 public class RepoModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IStudentRepo>().To<StudentRepo>();
        }
    }
```

HomeController

```
 private readonly ITest test;
        public HomeController(ITest test)
        {
            this.test = test;
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
           return View();
        }
```

Test(my service layer file)

```
  public class Test : ITest
    {
        private readonly IStudentRepo studentRepo;

        public Test(IStudentRepo studentRepo)
        {
            this.studentRepo = studentRepo;
        }

    }
```

Repo

```
  public class StudentRepo : IStudentRepo
    {
        private readonly ISession session;

        public StudentRepo(ISession session)
        {
            this.session = session;
        }
    }
```

When I look through my debugger at the session that is coming into my repo. It says the session is open and connected but the (session.Transaction).IsActive = false

Comment: Where are you starting your transaction?

Comment: lol ya that would help if I did that.

Comment: I guess the only thing. I am wondering is do I have to close the session or is it doing it automatically?

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc the latest version guarantees that any objects bound in request scope get disposed when the request ends. That is not necessarily the case with your implementation.

Comment: I recently took it becuase asp.net mvc 3 has something similar built in. Does it not do the same thing? Why does it matter would that not be a built thing in the InRequestScope() method not a mvc thing since I am assuming if your using a web forms application you would close the session as well.

Comment: @chobo2 as I understand it Ninject has had a problem with objects not being disposed right at HttpRequestEnd and staying alive after the request has ended. Just something to keep in mind. FYI you need to use the @ tag before someone's name otherwise they are not notified that you replied to them.

Comment: @Yads do you know if that existed in 2.0 or if that might have been a earlier version problem?

Comment: @chobo2, I know the bug existed at some point in 2.0. As of the latest version that is no longer the case. There is an HttpModule called `OnePerRequestModule` It's in the NInject namespace. It hooks into the EndRequest event and clears out all bindings associated with the current HttpContext (which is the scope when you specify an `InRequestScope` binding). Unless you're using Ninject.Web.Mvc, you need to manually call Init on the module.

Comment: @Yadas Hmm even with using the build in DI helper that came with mvc 3.0? So how would I manually call this Init? Where would I call it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently set up to use implicit transactions, which I don't believe are exposed through `session.Transaction`. Of course, [Use of implicit transactions is discouraged](http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions).