# Nhibernate mapping List<Class> where Class has its own table

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to create mapping for classes:

```
public class Employer
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Field> Fields { get; set; }
        public virtual string Location { get; set; }
        public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    }

public class Field
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; } 
    }
```

My mappings look like:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="lab" assembly="lab">

  <class name="Employer" table="Employer">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />

    <list name="Fields" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="EmployerId" />
      <index column="FieldIndex" />
      <one-to-many class="Field"/>
    </list>

    <property name="Location" />
    <property name="Phone" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="lab" assembly="lab">

  <class name="Field" table="Field">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Description" />
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

And code looks like:

```
var session = configuration.BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession();
var transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
var emp = new Employer();
emp.Name = "Mera";
emp.Fields = new List<Field> ();
emp.Fields.Add(new Field() { Description = "C#" });
emp.Fields.Add(new Field() { Description = "C++" });
emp.Location = "Street";
emp.Phone = "02";
session.Save(emp);
transaction.Commit();

var transaction2 = session.BeginTransaction();
var emp2 = new Employer();
emp2.Name = "Mera2";
emp2.Fields = session.CreateQuery("from Field").List<Field>();
emp2.Location = "Street";
emp2.Phone = "02";
session.Save(emp2);
transaction2.Commit();
```

This code just substitutes old entries in Field table for new one for the second employer. So Field table still has 2 records and Employer table has 2 records.

As you could understand I need that if 2 fields are equal (the same Description) both of 2 employers should have the same object references on it.

Comment: So each employer can have many fields, and each field can have many employers? Sounds like it should be a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JamesB has said in his comment this looks like a many-to-many relationship. Many-to-Many relationships require an intermediate table otherwise you will get the behavior you have seen.

To get the desired behavior you will need to create a new table called something like `EmployerFields`. This table will need to have two foreign key fields, one for `Employer` and the other for `Fields`, and a field for the index, `FieldIndex`. The FKs can be called something like `EmployerId` and `FieldId` respectively.

Then the list mapping will then need to be changed as shown below.

```
<list name="Fields" cascade="all-delete-orphan" table="EmployerFields">
  <key column="EmployerId" />
  <index column="FieldIndex" />
  <many-to-many class="Field" column="FieldId" />
</list>
```

Comment: Glad I could help. One thing I did note in both your questions was that you were creating a new SessionFactory each time. In application code this is a bad idea, generally the SessionFactory should be created once at the start of the application due to the expense of creating it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310691/nhibernate-good-complete-working-helper-class-for-managing-sessionfactory-sess) for an example helper implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the note, I started to create it in the constructor of DataAccess class, which is a singltone. So it is always created only once when the DataAccess is called for the first time.